# Change display language within an xamarin Android app

Tags: xamarin.android, localization

How can I change the display language within an app? I want that users with different cultures can work with one scanner without changing the global culture of the device.

I have a language button with a click event in which I call a method:

```
public void SetLocale(string language = "")
{
    Locale locale = String.IsNullOrEmpty(language)
                               ? new Locale("de-DE")
                               : new Locale(language);
    Locale.Default = locale;
    var config = new global::Android.Content.Res.Configuration();
    config.Locale = locale;
    var context = global::Android.App.Application.Context;
    context.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(config, context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
}
```

But unfortunately nothing happens when I press the button.

The click event is:

```
_btnen.Click += delegate
{
    SetLocale("en-GB");
};
```

Comment: If any of the answers has helped you, please consider voting is as a resolved/final answer.

Answer (score 3):

What can work for You, if the context can be forgotten (all property values can be lost), You can just force the `Activity` to redraw itself.

```
btn.Click += delegate
{
    SetLocale("en-GB");

    this.Recreate(); //this line
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With help of @Rafael Stahl, I found following solution:

```
_btnen.Click += delegate
{              
    Java.Util.Locale.Default = new Locale("en", "GB");
    Resources.Configuration.Locale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;
    Resources.UpdateConfiguration(Resources.Configuration, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.Class);
    StartActivity(intent);
};
```

Comment: This codes creates new `Activity`, which can lead into errors later. (You are leaving Youre previous window/activity behind, and working with new one with other locale). Not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers of user1230268 and Tatranskymedved:

```
_btnen.Click += delegate
{
    Java.Util.Locale.Default = new Locale("en", "GB");
    Resources.Configuration.Locale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;
    Resources.UpdateConfiguration(Resources.Configuration, Resources.DisplayMetrics);

    // Redraw
    this.Recreate();
};
```