# Changing language in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, translation

Long story short:
The app I wrote supports multiple language using `LangResource.{xx-XX}.resx` files in the `Translation` folder.

I apply the strings directly in xaml using

```
`xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:Elettric80.TP.Translations"`
```

in the `ContentPage` initial declaration, and

```
`Text="{x:Static resources:LangResource.{string}}"`
```

where needed.

On code side i just assign the translated strings using `LangResource.{string}`.

In page Option , which is a child of MainPage, I offer the possibility to select a language based on the available `resx` files.
Once selected I save the selected lang in the settings and reload the MainPage with

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
```

When the app restarts, I read the settings, get the selected language and execute

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
```

before `InitializeComponent();` is called.

The problem is that the MainPage is translated, but all the other pages keeps the previous language, unless I close the app, and restart it manually.

I also tried to use `DependencyService` to apply directly the language on Android side calling:

```
DependencyService.Get<ILanguageService>().SetLanguage(lang);
```

in c# and passing the language to the following method

```
public void SetLanguage(string lang)
{
    CultureInfo myCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = myCulture;

    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.Default = locale;
    var config = new global::Android.Content.Res.Configuration();
    config.Locale = locale;
    config.SetLocale(locale);
}
```

Still, the language changes only if I close the app and open it again.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Try to call the `Recreate` method to make the MainActivity  redraw itself after calling **SetLocale** command. Check the related link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978802/change-display-language-within-an-xamarin-android-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with `DependencyService`, calling

```
DependencyService.Get<ILanguageService>().SetLanguage(lang);
```

passing the language that has been selected (in the format "en"/"es"/"it"/etc...).

The interface is declared in ILanguageService.cs as:

```
namespace {namespace}
{
    public interface ILanguageService
    {
        void SetLanguage(string lang);
    }
}
```

The Android side is as follows:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof({namespace}.Droid.LanguageService))]

namespace {namespace}.Droid
{
    public class LanguageService : ILanguageService
    {
        public void SetLanguage(string lang)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang))
            {
                // Get application context
                Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;

                // Set application locale by selected language
                Locale.Default = new Locale(lang);
                context.Resources.Configuration.Locale = Locale.Default;
                context.ApplicationContext.CreateConfigurationContext(context.Resources.Configuration);
                context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.SetTo(context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);

                // Relaunch MainActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, new MainActivity().Class);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As before I set the app in the selected language reading it from the settings and applying  it with

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
```