# A better way to load localizations from server in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, localization

For now I see only one way - mark all translated strings as DynamicResources. After language change I can manually replace current strings to new strings from server. But it looks tricky...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin.Forms change UI language at runtime (XAML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410407/xamarin-forms-change-ui-language-at-runtime-xaml)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it looks like a bit more tricky than my solution :)

Comment: Another approach is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978802/change-display-language-within-an-xamarin-android-app .  Requires a little code on each platform, to get everything restarted with the new language. That example shows code you would put in android project; I am sure there are similar techniques on the other platforms.

Comment: The most standard way in Xamarin Forms is to use a "DependencyService". [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869735/changing-language-in-xamarin-forms) might be helpful.